# Ruby clean script

Tags: ruby, bash

I'm completely new to Ruby.
I'm trying to write a script that will delete all compiled files.
For example i have source files and a destination file and some intermediate files.
I need to keep source file and a destination file. The base filename is unknown, but if there's a 
file.c all other files will have 'file' basename, so there will be file.s, file.o and file

what I thought I can do is look for a 'foo.c' for example and if it exists delete all 'lower' files except for the target file. If there isnt foo.c file, then I'm looking for foo.s file, and delete all other files etc.

so I imagine i'd use Dir.entries to get an array of all filenames in a folder

If it is easier to do with bash script, i'll be glad to hear any suggestions

I tried

```
Dir.entries(".").each do filename
puts filename
end
```

and I can get file extension from that, and I can check if it's .s or .c for example, but if there is no .c present i don't want to delete .s file

this is my current code:

```
Dir.entries(".").each do |filename|
if File.extname(filename) == ".c"
   name = File.basename(filename, ".c")
   if File.exists?(name + ".s")
      File.delete(name + ".s")
   end
   ...
end
...
end
```

Comment: Why bother with ruby? Use a shell script.

Comment: @DaveNewton if you would be so kind, please make a suggestion

Comment: I don't get your question, if foo.c exists then delete all files which also are 'foo.any-other-extension' and keep foo.c? Then if 'foo.s' exists, keep 'foo.s' and delete other files containing 'foo.any_other_extension'?

Comment: That code doesn't look too far off. However somethings like Dir["./destination/*.c"].map {|f| File.basename(f)} might work better for getting all of the "foo.c" files.

Comment: Look into Rake. It's already got ruby tools for easily selecting files and mapping them to different extensions and `rake/clean` has pre-prepared objects for handling cleanup tasks. Not to mention that you can use Rake to replace the arcane syntax of tools like GNU Make with something more readable and flexible. Avdi Grimm has a 7 part intro to Rake on his blog. I recommend you check it out.

Comment: @DaveNewton I think this user wants to use Ruby to accomplish this task.

Comment: @Snarf Obviously. My point was that if they're "completely new to Ruby" it doesn't make much sense to do that, and the OP implied in their follow-up comment that non-Ruby solutions were fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
files_with_same_names = Dir.glob('*').group_by { |file| File.basename(file, '.*') } # this way we group files with the same base name

files_with_same_names.each_pair do |base_name, files_with_same_basename|
  extensions = ['.c', '.s'] # put the #1 priority extension first, the #2 priorty second etc.

  extensions.each do |extension|
    full_name = "#{base_name}#{extension}"
    if files_with_same_basename.include?(full_name)
      files_with_same_basename.delete(full_name) # delete the top-level name from our array
      files_with_same_basename.each do |file| # and delete the rest of the files
        puts "Deleting #{file}"# Replace puts "Deleting #{file}" with File.delete(file)
      end
    end
  end
```

end

I've tested it with these files:
a.c
a.d
b.s
b.h
b.o

and it was about to delete "a.d" (since it found a.c) and b.h and b.o (since it found b.s but not b.c).